# MYSQL ERROR 1096 - NO TABLES USED - CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am using a custom query as the Active Record equivelant did not work for me.

When placing the Query in my Database Software SQLYOG it works fine however in CodeIgniter it says

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1096
>
> No tables used
>
> SELECT *
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\midas\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT intervention.department_id, department_name, COUNT(*)
FROM intervention 
LEFT JOIN department ON department.department_id = intervention.department_id

GROUP BY intervention.department_id, department.department_name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
LIMIT 1
```

It is a bit of a strange problem.

Here is my Schema also:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WstcX.png

Comment: I don't think it's the posted query thats causing the error.

Comment: Can you show the code that you build the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

This will not work. As noted below only `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(table.field)` work.

I think you need to specify which table you are using `COUNT(*)` on, so change it to something like `COUNT(department.*)` or `COUNT(intervention.*)`

Comment: @Hunter: You have to either count on a specific field (`count(table.field)`) or count everything `(count(*))`, you can't count on `sometable.*`.

Comment: You are right my mistake, I was thinking about selecting all from a table like that. table.. Ill edit above.

Comment: I didnt post a new answer, I merely posted that my solution wont work.

Comment: Yes but I tried COUNT(intervention.department_id) and it still gives me ERROR 1096

Comment: Its ok I figured it out I am not meant to use get() after query.

Answer (score 7):

Its ok I figured it out.

For custom query in Codeigniter you cannot use get method after.

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom queries in Code Igniter you must return the result (Database object) to controller, because get method (from `$this->db`) doesn´t work.