# SQL: distinct in where clause and fetch the result

Tags: mysql

I am trying this from last 2 hours and used many methods like MIN(), DISTINCT and CONCAT() but couldn't able to get my desired result. Need an expert to take a look at my code and tell me where i am doing wrong.

My Database Structure is

```
ID  | message_security_code | employer_ID | seeker_ID | chat_message  | sent_by  | dated
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 66666666              |  45         |  78       |  hello        | employer | 2017-05-23
2   | 44444444              |  45         |  78       |  hello        | seeker   | 2017-05-23
3   | 55555555              |  45         |  78       |  hello        | employer | 2017-05-23
4   | 66666666              |  45         |  78       |  hello        | employer | 2017-05-23
```

I want to fetch all results but only one record will show if the `message_security_code` the latest one order by ID also where employer_ID = my given id

this is what i am trying from few last hours

> TRY 1

`"SELECT DISTINCT message_security_code FROM pp_chat_messages WHERE employer_ID = '$id'"`

> TRY 2

`"SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, employer_ID, seeker_ID, chat_message, sent_by, dated FROM pp_chat_messages WHERE employer_ID = '$id' GROUP BY message_security_code"`

Expected Result : if the `employer_ID` is 45

```
ID  | message_security_code | employer_ID | seeker_ID | chat_message
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 66666666              |  45         |  78       |  hello
2   | 44444444              |  45         |  78       |  hello
3   | 55555555              |  45         |  78       |  hello
```

Comment: mysql database i am using php codeigniter

Comment: Show the expected result for you sample data

Comment: Have you tried static value instead of variable `'$id'`

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam yes gives me error

Comment: what error it gives

Comment: `A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1096

No tables used

SELECT *

Filename: /home/choudharyjji/public_html/caliphp/models/chat_message_model.php

Line Number: 113`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927940/mysql-error-1096-no-tables-used-codeigniter for information about that error in CodeIgniter

Comment: Where the columnx `sent_by, dated` comes from?

Comment: they are the next two columns which i didn't added in my question structure

Comment: This is an earliest-per-group problem and has been answered numerous times here in SO. You can easily find a solution to a problem that is similar to your if you just google sth like *first row in each group MySQL*

Comment: Sorry @GiorgosBetsos i didn't mean to duplicate things here . did google many times when i didn't get anything i reached here. Sorry again for any inconvenience

Comment: Just replace `max()` in the duplicate topic with `min()` and there you go. There are questions specifically for `min()` as well, but the explanation is a lot better in the linked `max()` question.

Comment: @Shadow tried it still gets nothing please check once where i am doing wrong `"SELECT ID, MIN(message_security_code) FROM pp_chat_messages GROUP BY ID"`

Comment: The query looks ok from a syntax point of view.